# How to set packaging to pom in Gradle instead of defaulting to jar

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I have a project that generates a Bill of Materials (BOM). When I execute gradle build it generates an empty jar, containing only a META-INF folder.

However I am able to publish the pom (BOM) to Nexus correctly, with the side effect of also uploading the empty jar.

According to the maven plugin doc https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html we should be able to set the packaging:

> packaging  archiveTask.extension
>
> Here, uploadTask and archiveTask refer to the tasks used for uploading
>   and generating the archive

How can I set the packaging to pom?

Example of Gradle uploaded pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ttt.a</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-bom</artifactId>
  <version>Something-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

When I upload it with maven instead of gradle, there is an additional:

```
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

**UPDATE:**

Full build.gradle config:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://myrepo"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.4.RELEASE"
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5"
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.7'
    } }

apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'maven' apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management" apply plugin: "jacoco" apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.convert' apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

group = project.properties['groupId'] version = project.properties['version'].toString()

description = """Bill of Materials"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.8 targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    xxx = '1.0.0'
    yyy = '1.2.0'
    ... }

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://myrepo"
    } }

dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency "com.myorg:xxx:${xxx}"
        dependency "com.myorg:yyy:${yyy}"
        ...
    } }

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            snapshotRepository(url: 'http://myrepo') {
                authentication(userName: "$System.env.NEXUS_USER", password: "$System.env.NEXUS_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    } }

asciidoctor {
    sourceDir = file('src/docs/asciidoc/')
    sources {
        include '*.adoc'
    }
    outputDir = file("build/docs/${version}") }

task generateDummyBom {
    doLast {
        project.buildDir.mkdirs()
        new File("$project.buildDir/dummy.pom").write("<project></project>\n")
    }
    ext.bomFile = file("$project.buildDir/dummy.pom") }

artifacts {
    archives(generateDummyBom.bomFile) {
        builtBy generateDummyBom
    } }

jar.enabled = false
```

Comment: Did you try to manually set the `packaging` property ? to `pom` for instance ?

Comment: Yes I did and it didn't work :(

Comment: could you add to your post the relevant part of the `build.gradle` file please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the maven plugin seems to ignore the `packaging` property. After some experimentation, I found that it sets the `packaging` property to the extension of the file in your artifact. So, the way to get the `packaging` property set to `pom` is to create a dummy artifact with a file having a `.pom` extension, as below.

```
// The real file that we want to publish is the pom generated implicitly by the
// maven publishing plugin.
//
// We need to generate at least one file that we can call an archive so that the
// maven plugin will actually publish anything at all. Luckily, if the file
// that we call an archive is a .pom file, it's magically discarded, and we are
// only left with the implicitly-generated .pom file.
//
// We need the extension of the file to be `.pom` so that the maven plugin will
// set the pom packaging to `pom` (i.e. `<packaging>pom</packaging>`). Otherwise,
// packaging would be set to `xml` if our only file had an `.xml` extension.
task generateDummyBom {
  doLast {
    // Since we don't depend on anything else, we have to create the build dir
    // ourselves.
    project.buildDir.mkdirs()
    // The file actually has to have xml in it, or Sonatype will reject it
    new File("$project.buildDir/${project.artifactId}.pom").write("<project></project>\n")
  }
  ext.bomFile = file("$project.buildDir/${project.artifactId}.pom")
}

artifacts {
  archives(generateDummyBom.bomFile) {
    builtBy generateDummyBom
  }
}

jar.enabled = false
```

**Update**: If you apply the java plugin, you will need to remove the jar archive from your archives.

```
// Remove the default jar archive which is added by the 'java' plugin.
configurations.archives.artifacts.with { archives ->
  def artifacts = []
  archives.each {
    if (it.file =~ 'jar') {
      // We can't just call `archives.remove(it)` here because it triggers
      // a `ConcurrentModificationException`, so we add matching artifacts
      // to another list, then remove those elements outside of this iteration.
      artifacts.add(it)
    }
  }
  artifacts.each {
    archives.remove(it)
  }
}
```

**Second update**: Replaced "dummy.pom" with "${project.artifactId}" above.

Comment: Hi Garret, I just tested your solution but it doesn't work. I see there's no jar anymore but the new dummy.pom file, so far so good. The problem is that `./gradlew -DNEXUS_PASSWORD=$NEXUS_PASSWORD -DNEXUS_USER=$NEXUS_USER clean build upload --no-daemon` ends up with this error: `Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.  Could not publish configuration 'archives' Cannot publish artifact 'myreleasetrain.jar (com.myorg:myreleasetrain:Callao-SR5-SNAPSHOT)' (/home/myreleasetrain/build/libs/myreleasetrain-Autumn-GA-SNAPSHOT.jar) as it does not exist.`

Comment: I added an update for how to remove the jar artifact that is added by default when you use the java plugin.

Comment: With your update the pom is successfully uploaded...well almost. What I am seeing in Nexus is a pom for an artifactId named dummy. Just replacing `dummy.pom` by  `${project.artifactId}.pom ` makes it work like a charm.

Comment: I updated my answer with `${project.artifactId}`. Thanks!

Comment: I get `${project.artifactId}` being undefined and tried replacing it with `${project.name}-${project.version}`, which does eliminate that error, but now I get an error about it not being able to find the jar, which seems dumb to me because I thought the whole point of this solution was to stop it looking for the jar. :(

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Garrett's solution to work, but I did have success like this:

```
dependencies {
    // ...Omitted...
}

tasks.named('generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication') {
    pom.with {
        description = 'Parent BOM'
        withXml {
            // ...Omitted...
        }
    }
}

// Removing all jar artifacts from the mavenJava publication
// appears to automagically cause packaging to be set to 'pom'!
publishing.publications.named('mavenJava') {
    artifacts.removeIf { artifact ->
        artifact.extension == 'jar'
    }
}
```

Comment: ```generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication {
 pom.packaging = "pom"
}```